# Modal UIViewController appears blank

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm appending code to an existing app to add a modal loginView, the old project does not use xib, and the new view controller does.

The present project load its rootViewController this way

```
- (void) loadView
{
// this should take up the entire screen...
UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
self.view = view;

sideBar =
    [[SideBarView alloc] init];
sideBar.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:sideBar];

pageView =
    [[PageView alloc] initWithTitle:DataEntryTitle
                             client:client];
pageView.rootViewController = self;
//I added this to instantiate the new view controller
_aLoginView = [[LoginViewController alloc]initWithUser:aUser];

[self.view addSubview:pageView];
}
```

To launch the modal view controller I'm using this code.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

  _aLoginView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
  [self presentViewController:_aLoginView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

As long as I understand the reason for the modal LoginView appearing blank is that I'm creating a new instance of it, instead of calling the existing xib definition. Does someone know what should I do to reference the xib? The old project does not use storyboard, nor xib files.

Thanks,

With your info I think I'm doing something wrong in LoginViewController.m, but I don't know exactly what.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (id)initWithUser:(verifyUser *)aUser
{
self = [super initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    _UserModel = aUser;
}
return self;
}
```

Comment: Is the files owner of the XIB set to the controller in question?

Comment: I don't understand your question, the xib has the same name than the .h and .m it is LoginViewController.xib, but I'm calling it form a UIViewController named RootViewController.

Comment: Yes you still need to set the files owner in the XIB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create the view controller by loading it from the nib

```
[[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNib:@"nib file name" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]];
```

If you want to keep your `initWithUser:` initializer you should be able to do

```
self = [super initWithNib:@"nib file name" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new about this, Does "nib file name" mean the name of the class? "LoginViewController"? Thanks.

Comment: Typically it does. XCode will be default create file LoginViewController.xib when you create a view controller called LoginViewController. If you have a file like that in your project and it cannot find it at runtime you need to check the copy files build phase.

Comment: Please see my edition. I don't see the xib file in the bundle. How can I force its copy?

Comment: Select your project in the left-hand panel in XCode. Select your build target in the main view. Select Build Phases at the top. One of the build phases is "Copy Bundle Resources". Add the xib file if it is not preset. (I cannot create a screenshot right now, let me know if you need one and I will later tonight.)

Comment: I tried to do this, but the xib file does not appear in the list, only .h and .m  I created a new UIViewController to test and its .xib does not appear either.

Comment: That is strange, I would expect XCode to add them by default. Can you try to locate the xib file in your project browser and drag it to the copy bundle resources build phase?

Answer (score 0):

The files owner of your xib is not set.

Open your xib and select the file owner option in the top left

[image]

Then on the right pane set the files owner to your view controller:
[image]

**FOOTNOTE**

As an aside, you don't need to set the frame of your view controller in viewDidLoad. It isn't a ViewControllers responsibility to evaluate its own size. A view controller is merely responsible for maintaining the relationship between the model and the view. It is the responsibility of the container or parent ViewController to set the size.

Happy coding

Comment: The file's owner is LoginViewController.

Comment: Firstly, you don't need a reference to the loginViewController. Secondly, try doing a normal push and see what happens. My suspicion is that your viewController is not calling loadNibNamed. Any chance you have overridden loadView in the Login Controller?

Comment: I override the initialization method since I need to use a model, I don't know if I did it wrong. See my question edition above please.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly call super initWithNibName. This is automatically called since you don't override loadView in the LoginViewController. Its possible that your XIB has just gotten out of whack. Try creating a brand new XIB and a new controller and pushing that. If that works then you might need to either delete your XIB and re-add it

Comment: Thanks It worked after recreation. It was a sum of things. Somehow the xib ended inside the en.lproj folder and the Location option was disabled.  During the recreation I found a button pointing to IBOutlet and a IBAction, I don't know if that was the origin of the issue.

Comment: These things happen:) glad u sorted!